# rosbag record -j and depression again

Tags: ros

I record a rosbag using command "rosbag record -O bag /velodyne_points -j", after that, when running the data, the computer decompress it, can I decompress it manually.
below is for futher information:

> compression:  bz2 [3355/3355 chunks; 39.12%]
>
> uncompressed: 3.4 GB @ 7.3 MB/s
>
> compressed:   1.3 GB @ 2.9 MB/s (39.12%)

can I decompress it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `rosbag decompress` (check [rosbag/Commandline](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline#rosbag_decompress) for more info). For example, running `rosbag decompress bag.bag` will generate a decompressed `bag.bag` and compressed (intact) `bag.orig.bag` files.